# Sparse coding and dictionary learning using opencv and c++

Tags: c++, opencv, dictionary, image-processing, svd

I am trying to perform text image restoration and I can find no proper documentation on how to perform OMP or K-SVD in `C++` using `opencv`.

1. I have over 1000 training images of different sizes so do I divide images into equal sized patches or resize all images? How do I construct the signal matrix X?
2. What other pre-processing steps are required for sparse coding? How to actually perform K-SVD on color images?
3. What data type is available in `OpenCV` for an image dictionary and how do I initialize the Dictionary D?

I have these very basic questions and have tried to use various libraries but they don't make the working very clear.

Comment: any luck? I also want the same code to learn KSVD.

Comment: Nothing yet..still figuring out a way to normalize columns of initial dictionary..

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://suzuichibolgpg.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-275.html) code useful. This is the only implementation in [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) I have come across so far. I guess it uses a single image for dictionary learning whereas I have to use at least 1000 images. But it certainly provides a good guideline.